# Как вернуть пароль wifi в android к читабельному виду?

Tags: android, wifi, password

Где хранится пароль от файла в андроид допустим мы знаем. Интересует вопрос как его "превратить " к читальному виду.
Хранится он в файле /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
 Но не знаю всегда ли или только в последних обновлениях на Samsung его вид стал 92e9061a1677f6223407f5.... а не обычный  текст.
Вопрос как его преобразить к нормальному тексту.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пароль в чистом виде не хранят, а делают из него хеш. Статья по теме: [Хеширование](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Хеш нельзя восстановить, но можно сгенерировать хеши для разных наборов паролей и зная текущий хеш попробовать угадать пароль. Используя, к примеру [радужные таблицы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0).

Функции хеширования бывают разные: [MD5](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), [SHA-1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) и т.п.

Хеши еще бывают "солеными", это когда перед хеширование к данным добавляется какая-то строка, которую знают только определенные стороны, например: клиент и сервер.

Тогда, если хеш достанут, то "распознавание" исходных данных из хеша будет затруднено.

Пример на псевдо-языке:

```
md5("qwerty")        -> "d8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4"

salt = "DEADDEADDEAD"
md5("qwerty" + salt) -> "78b78a2f404d4947f67c905f46e7ffd5"
```

т.к. обе стороны знают соль, то смогут повторить хеш для одних и тех же данных. Поэтому, в базе данных пароли нельзя хранить в открытом виде, а хешировать с солью: если базу угонят, то злоумышленникам будет невозможно восстановить исходные пароли.

Comment: Где то я встречал калькулятор хешей.

Comment: В видосах на ютубе парОли не encrypted ксати.

Comment: Есть и сайты для поиска значения по хешу, и программы для взлома wpa, например: https://habr.com/post/334966/

Comment: Сейчас внесу точность. Телефон подключён к вайфай.  Пароль от вайфая сохранен на телефоне  но он encrypted. Есть программы которые показивают его в виде текстак примеру" wifi password recovery". И достают они его с этого же файла. Но если я ручками залезу в этот файл то я не смогу его использовать так как он зашифрован. Я не уверен что там настолько сложный алгоритм расшифровки.

Comment: @gil9red, я правильно понял, что при, например, регистрации юзера по логину и паролю на сайте его пароль преобразуется в хэш, пишется в БД и при следующем логине введённый пароль опять таки преобразуется в хэш и сравнивается с тем, что в БД лежит? Т.е. в теории может быть коллизия и несколько паролей могут залогинить одного и того же юзера?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не думаю, иначе можно было перехватывать хеши и, запоминая их, самим отправлять на сервера. Тот пример с солью был примером. Работа с сайтами проходит по https, поэтому логин/пароль можно передавать в открытом виде, но на самом сервере, получая пароль сделать из него хеш (с солью) и пойти в базу, проверяя есть ли такой логин с таким паролем-хешем. Для надежности, можно хеш циклично подсчитать, типо: `sha256(sha256(sha256(<пароль> + <соль>)))`. Т.к. сервер будет знать соль и количество циклов хеширования, то при угоне базы пароли будут в относительной безопасности

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, стало чуть-чуть понятнее)